# OpenGL - Are animations done by shaders?

Tags: c++, opengl, animation, shader, vertex

I started to study OpenGL and I learned how to show figures and stuff using Vertex and Fragment shader.
I created a (very) stylized man, and now I want it to move his arm and legs.
The question is: should I change vertex data in the VBO, directly in a timer function called in the main (as I did), or is it a job that should be done in the vertex shader, without touching vertex data?

I suppose the answer is the first one, but I feel like it overload CPU, instead of make the GPU work.

Answer (score 14):

Both ways will work fine: if your aim it to utilise the GPU more then do the transformations in vertex shaders, otherwise you could use the CPU.  Bear in mind however if checking for collisions you need data present at the CPU side....

In essence:

Doing the manipulation on the GPU means you only need to send the mesh data once, then you can send the matrix transformations to deform or animate it. 
This is ideal as it greatly reduces the bandwidth of data trasmission between CPU->GPU. 
It can also mean that you can upload just one copy of the mesh to the GPU and apply transforms for many different instances of the mesh to achieve varied but similar models (ie bear mesh sent to GPU make an instance at scale *2 scale *1 and scale *0.5 for Daddy bear, Mummy bear and Baby bear, and then send a Goldilocks mesh, now you have 2 meshes in memory to get 4 distinct models).

The transformed meshes however are not immediately available on the CPU side, so mesh-perfect Collision Detection will be more intensive.

Animating on the CPU means you have access to the transformed mesh, with the major caveat that you must upload that whole mesh to the GPU each frame and for each instance: more work, more data and more memory used up on both CPU and GPU sides.

### CPU Advantages

- Current accurate meshes are available for whatever purpose you require at all times.

### CPU Disadvantages

- massive data transfer between CPU and GPU: one transfer per instance per frame per model

### GPU Advantages:

- Upload less mesh data (once if you only need variations of the one model)
- Transform individual instances in a fast parallelised way
- CPU->GPU bandwidth minimised: only need to send tranformations
- GPU is parallelised and can handle mesh data far more efficiently than a CPU

### GPU Disadvantages

- Meshes are not readily available for mesh-perfect collision detection

---

### Mitigations to offset the overheads of transferring GPU data back to CPU:

Utilise bounding Boxes(axis aligned or non axis aligned as per your preference): this allows a small dataset to represent the model on the CPU side (8 points per box, as opposed to millions of points per mesh).  If the bounding boxes collide, then transfer the mesh from GPU -> CPU and do the refined calculation to get an exact mesh to mesh collision detection.  This gives the best of both worlds for the least overhead.

As the performance of the GPU could be tens, hundreds or even thousands of time higher than a CPU at processing meshes it quickly becomes evident why for performant coding as much as possible in this area is farmed out to the GPU.

Hope this helps:)

Comment: There is a nice demo of how to carry out shader animation at http://www.belanecbn.sk/3dtutorials/index.php?id=20 , another set of useful links here http://www.lcg.ufrj.br/Cursos/GPUProg/GLSLfirst and some here http://www.antongerdelan.net/opengl/ and finally  a handy list of excercises at http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/

Comment: The first link in that comment sends me to a site which was blocked by my ESET antivirus saying it has a trojan, so be careful.

Comment: They did not have any trojans when posted, however I will check them out when I get home, maybe post the original code somewhere else if I need to:)

Comment: No worries, I did see it was from 2014, and there's no way of knowing if a link will go bad in the future, so just wanted to point it out to anyone else who comes across your answer/comment in the future!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the platform and OpenGL version you can do the animations by changing the data from the vertex buffer directly(software animations) or by associating groups of vertices with corresponding animation matrices(hardware animations).

If you chose second approach(recommended where it is possible) you can send one or more of these matrices to the vertex shader as uniforms, maybe associating some "weight" factor for each matrix.

Please keep in mind that software animation will overload the CPU when you have a very high number of vertices and hardware animations would be almost free, you just multiply the vertex with correct matrix instead of model-view-projection one in the shader. Also GPUs are highly optimized for doing math operations and the are very fast compared to CPUs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm new in this "sector", so I didn't really understand how to do hardware animations.
What do you mean by "animation matrices", and what is this "weight" factor?

Comment: You can check this tutorial from OpenGL web page: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Skeletal_Animation